# TypeScript: Access global type hidden by local class definition?

Tags: class, typescript, global, typescript1.8

Lets assume i have a class which has the same name as an previously defined type which is defined inside *lib.d.ts*. How would i make use of that type within this class.

For example, i have the class *Event*, which has to deal with the browsers *Event* object, which is defined as an interface in lib.d.ts.

```js
export class Event { // own definition of Event which hides original Event

  public dealWithBrowserEvent(event: Event): void { // Event object defined by lib.d.ts
    // deal with it
  }

}
```

How would i tell Typescript that this are two different types. Of course i could simply rename my class, but i don't want to do that, because the name is perfect for my use case.

Comment: I would suggest using namespaces, since that's what they're for (that is, to disambiguate names).

Comment: I'm not aware that TypeScript would support a real concept for namespaces. The types defined inside lib.d.ts have no namespace and the code I'm writing is already in my own "namespace"/module. That's why I have this name collision. How would a solution, using namespaces, look like?

Comment: Something like `module My.Namespace { export class Event { ...` Then you could specify your Event class by `My.Namespace.Event`.

Comment: That's what I'm already doing. My Event class is already in a module named 'xyz/event'. I have no problem accessing this class from somewhere  else as xyz.event.Event, but i have the issue to use the type Event (defined without namespace in lib.d.ts) inside the class Event, because of the name collision.

Comment: Okay, that information wasn't in the question, so I couldn't know. Seems like you should name your class something else....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime i found a quite doable solution. I defined an additional module which exports renamed interfaces. If i import this module, i can use the renamed types as if they would be original types.

browser.ts

```js
// Event will be the one from lib.d.ts, because the compiler does not know anything about 
// the class Event inside this module/file.
// All defined properties will be inherited for code completion.
export interface BrowserEvent extends Event {
    additionalProperty1: SomeType;
    additionalProperty2: SomeType;
}
```

If you don't need additional properties you can just do type aliasing:

browser.ts

```js
// Alias for Event
export type BrowserEvent = Event;
```

event.ts

```
import {BrowserEvent} from './browser.ts';

export class Event { // Definition of Event hides original Event, but not BrowserEvent

  public dealWithBrowserEvent(event: BrowserEvent): void {
    // deal with it
  }

}
```

I'm quite happy with this solution, but maybe there is a even better solution.

Comment: You could just use `type BrowserEvent = Event` to alias it.

Comment: Right. This is also an option, and preferable in my demo case. Defining an interface does more or less the same, but also allows to add additional properties which might not be defined by lib.d.ts. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can archive this by doing so:

E.ts:

```
class CustomEvent 
{ 
    public dealWithBrowserEvent(event: Event): void 
    { 

    }
}

export default CustomEvent;
```

A.ts:

```
import Event from './E'

export class SomeClass 
{ 
    //Parameter e here is instance of your CustomEvent class
    public someMethod(e: Event): void 
    { 
        let be: any;
        //get browser event here
        e.dealWithBrowserEvent(be)
    }
}
```

More on declaration merging, and what can be merged and what not: [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Declaration%20Merging.md)

I strongly recommend you not doing so. This code will lead to a lot of confusion for your colleagues reading/modifying it later, let alone headache of not being able to use in the same file standard class for Event.

Comment: I tried to do it that way. But in the end i wasn't happy that the method parameter was of the wrong type during type checking. It also broke auto completion inside the IDE. JavaScript/TypeScript has some serious issues with colliding names. :(